# IOrchardShellEvents Implementation ConfigurationManager

Tags: .net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

When I try to access AppSettings and ConnectionStrings in my IOrchardShellEvents implementation, it doesn't work.

It seems to be accessing values from the root web.config (not my custom module).

How can I get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web.config in modules can't be used for that. Create your own site settings instead. http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Adding-custom-settings